# Selecting the first record for each group and updating it using value from another table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, sql-update

I have 2 tables `Table 1` & `Table 2`. I have to select the first record for each `EMP_ID` based on the min START_DATE from table 2 and update it with the CREATION_DATE from TABLE 1. I have tried with below query. But I am getting the error as SQL Error:

> ORA-00904: "IP"."CREATION_DATE": invalid identifier 00904.
>   00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause:    *Action:

I am not sure on how to accomplish this as I am new to Oracle. Any suggestions would be valuable. Sample screenshot for reference.

[image: screenshot]

**QUERY:**

```
UPDATE 
    (SELECT PSH.EMP_ID,PSH.START_DATE,EM.CREATION_DATE FROM EMP_MAIN EM 
 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT EMP_ID,START_DATE FROM (SELECT EMP_ID,START_DATE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY EMP_ID, START_DATE) 
    AS RN   FROM EMP_STATUS) WHERE RN=1) ES 
ON ES.EMP_ID = EM.PROJECT_ID) 
SET EM.START_DATE = ES.CREATION_DATE;
```

Comment: Have you studied UPDATE structure? I think you will find yourself whats wrong, after that. Useful web-page https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this sort of thing much easier to do using the `MERGE` statement than the `UPDATE` statement.  The reason is that you can write a query to `SELECT` the rows that way you want them to look after the operation and then use that `SELECT` as the row source for your `MERGE` to make it happen.

I am not bothering to create your table structure in my database (`CREATE TABLE` DDL with `INSERTs` would be nice when posting a question), so there may be typos/syntax errors here, but this should work:

```
MERGE INTO table2 t2
USING ( 
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  t2.rowid t2_row_id,
        row_number() over ( partition by t1.emp_id
                            order by t2.start_date ) rn,
        t1.creation_date new_start_date
FROM    table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id
) WHERE rn = 1
) u
ON ( t2.rowid = u.t2_row_id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t2.start_date = u.new_start_date;
```